# Example of use TArrayfield in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to store in a `TFDmemTable` an array of integers eg. `ar : array[0..N] of integer` where `N` is variable.

I know that I can use a `BLOB` field but I prefer to use a `TArrayField`.

I searched for a simple example but I didn't find one.

Can somebody give such an example, please ?

Comment: @MBo TArrayField is a database field representing an array. Only a minority of databases support this (f.i. InterBase). I'm not sure if TFDMemTable does.

Comment: @MBo. No, I'm looking for an example on dataset's TArrayField that stores the contents of an non fixed length array of integer

Comment: @UweRaabe. TFDmemTable seems not to complaint when I do "if assigned(Omades.fieldbyname('aArray')) then ....", but I don't know how to use it

Comment: TArrayField offers a Fields property returning a Field for each array element. Being derived from TObjectField it inherits all its properties and methods.